# Why is printing this formatted string causing a syntax error?

Tags: python, printing, format, output

I have been trying to use Python's new `print` formating for days now.  It's gotten to the point that I have cut and pasted several book examples in an attempt to examine the issue.

```
print '{0} and {1}'.format('spam', 'eggs')
```

Even this example is yielding:

```
print '{0} and {1}'.format('spam', 'eggs')
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's going on?

Comment: What version of python are you using?  If you are using python 3, `print` must be called as a function: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Python 3 requires parentheses around your parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  :

```
print('{0} and {1}'.format('spam', 'eggs'))
```

In Python 3 `print` is not a statement and has to be called as `print()`

**Output:**

```
spam and eggs
```